# db2 query passed in parameter is ignored

Tags: xml, db2, xquery

I have a db2 query

```
SELECT SECTIONTITLE, VMETE.COALESCE_XML(XMLQUERY('$c/Details/UserResource[ResourceGroup=@VmeMerchantId_0]' passing i.SECTIONCONTENT as "c"), i.SECTIONCONTENT) as SECTIONCONTENT 
FROM VMETE.IPSP_CONFIGURATION i 
WHERE ("IPSPID" = @IPSP_ID_0) AND ("EFFECTIVETO" = @EFFECTIVE_TO_0) ORDER BY SORTORDER
```

which has 3 parameters
            @VmeMerchantId_0
            @IPSP_ID_0
    @EFFECTIVE_TO_0

and in my command object, 
there're three parameters

```
[0] = {@VmeMerchantId_0}
[1] = {@IPSP_ID_0}
[2] = {@EFFECTIVE_TO_0}
```

why only the [1][2] is passed into the query, and [0] is ignored?

COALESCE_XML is a function I wrote, you can think it is COALESCE

Comment: Ignored as in the query complains about too few parameters?

Comment: the db2 doesn't complain anything, the result set is not what it is supposed to be. Is it possible to see the raw query after the db2 accepts the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
XMLQUERY('$c/Details/UserResource[ResourceGroup=$var]' 
   passing i.SECTIONCONTENT as "c", @VmeMerchantId_0 as "var")
```

Comment: I'm so tired of this fking db2 statement.

Comment: ERROR [42610] [IBM][DB2/SUN64] SQL0418N A statement contains a use of an untyped parameter marker or a null value that is not valid. SQLSTATE=42610

Comment: I'm almost sure that the db2 statement is no less tired of you... :) What is the data type of @VmeMerchantId_0? And what is the type of the ResourceGroup element? You may need to [explicitly CAST()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023459.html) @VmeMerchantId_0 to the correct type if they are different, and may be enclose `$var` in double quotes if it should be a string.